# How to add line to file using terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am new to linux. I want to make a automated script for compilation of cm11 form my device and this is my script

```
#/bin/bash
cd cm11/.repo/
rm -rf local_manifests
mkdir local_manifests
cd local_manifests
touch kyleve.xml
echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" >> kyleve.xml
echo "<manifest>" >> kyleve.xml
echo "<project name="Grace5921/device_samsung_kyleve" path="device/samsung/kyleve" revision="cm11" remote="github"/>" >> kyleve.xml
echo "<project name="Grace5921/vendor_samsung_kyleve" path="vendor/samsung/kyleve" revision="cm11" remote="github"/>" >> kyleve.xml
echo "<project name="Grace5921/kernel_samsung_kyleve" path="kernel/samsung/kyleve" revision="cm11" remote="github"/>" >> kyleve.xml
echo "</manifest>" >> kyleve.xml
cd
cd cm11
repo sync -j4
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch
brunch kyleve
echo "Done!"
```

But echo command adds this line to kyleve.xml

```
<project name=Grace5921/device_samsung_kyleve path=device/samsung/kyleve revision=cm11 remote=github/>
```

but i need this line in my output file

```
<project name="Grace5921/device_samsung_kyleve" path="device/samsung/kyleve" revision="cm11" remote="github"/>
```

those double inverted commas are messing which command can work in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes to make the string literal:

```
echo '<project name="Grace5921/device_samsung_kyleve" path=\
  "device/samsung/kyleve" revision="cm11" remote="github"/>' >>kyleve.xml
```

Or escape the relevant double quotes with `\`:

```
echo "<project name=\"Grace5921/device_samsung_kyleve\" \
  path=\"device/samsung/kyleve\" revision=\"cm11\" remote=\"github\"/>" >>kyleve.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`) to surround your line.
Example:

```
echo "myQuoted line "foobar" " >> test.txt
echo 'myQuoted line "foobar" ' >> test.txt

cat test.txt
myQuoted line foobar
myQuoted line "foobar"
```